# "Operation Search and Merge": VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to scavange together a macro which will merge several .CSV files.

However, the data I need in said file (GPS data) is located in different rows of column A. I therefor need it to search for part of a string, in this case there are a few strings related to GPS, but I only need GPS latitud and longitude (which will always be found one after another).

Any help is appreciated! The code might look a bit.. like shit, ive been trying to mess with it to make it work together!

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim directory As Object
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim S_Lat, S_Long, D_Lat, D_Long As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim icount As Integer
Dim icount2 As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then '-1 = yes or true
        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
        MsgBox "FilePath not selected!", , "Path selecter"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 2

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all .csv files in the folder path.
FileName = dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")

SummarySheet.Range("A1") = "Filnamn"
SummarySheet.Range("B1") = "Latitud"
SummarySheet.Range("C1") = "Longitud"

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""

    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & FileName)

    ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

    ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.

    For i = 1 To 200
        If InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), "GPS Latitude") <> 0 Then 'If GPS appears in the string then
            icount = i
            icount2 = icount + 1

            Set S_Lat = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & icount) ' Set the S_Lat variable
            Set S_Long = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & icount2) ' Set the S_Long variable

            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.

    ' SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow).Value = S_Lat.Value  ***** Didnt work? ******
    ' SummarySheet.Range("C" & NRow).Value = S_Long.Value ***** Didnt work? ******

    Set D_Lat = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set D_Long = SummarySheet.Range("C" & NRow)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.

    D_Lat.Value = S_Lat.Value
    D_Long.Value = S_Long.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + D_Lat.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = dir()
Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
' SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: You are searching an lcase’d string, but your search string is mixed case

Comment: Thanks Wallyeye, I should've realized that. Helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

This simple code is not giving you a complete working macro, it will Look for "Latitude" in column A and when found it will transfer the cel.value, and the cel.value below it, to two rows side-by-side in column B and column C on the same worksheet. You will need to wrap it inside your `Workbooks.Open` loop, modify the Range in the source worksheet to include a last row, include a last row for your new workbook's worksheet and add it to the code inside the `If` statement. Try to work this into your code and when you encounter problems, you can return to SO and ask a specific question concerning your macro. The macro was tested with actual longitudes and latitudes, in column A, an placed in columns B and C side-by-side.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cel In Range("A1:A38")
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Latitude") Then
        x = x + 1
            Cells(x, 2).Value = cel.Value
            Cells(x, 3).Value = cel.Offset(1).Value
    End If
Next cel
```